# Importing files in Python 3.4

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, module, python-import

I'm having trouble importing my own Python file. My file structure looks as such:

```
caboose2\
    __init__.py
    caboose.py
    bot\
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        config.ini
```

In the `settings.py` file there is a method, `get_config()` that uses `configparser` to parse the `config.ini` file to gather values for settings that are stored in a dict.

The contents of `caboose.py` are simple:

```
import bot
settings = bot.settings.get_config()
```

`bot\\__init__.py` contains:

```
import settings
```

And `settings.py` just contains the method `get_config()`. The method works fine; it was originally in the `caboose.py` file, but for cleanliness, I wanted to move it to its own file.

However, when I run the caboose.py file, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "caboose.py", line 2, in <module>
  import bot
File "D:\Brogramming\python\caboose2\bot\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  import settings
ImportError: No module named 'settings'
```

I'm sure there's some fundamental part of importing modules/files in Python that I'm not understanding, and I've decided to ask for help. Thank you for your time and any possible answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing the issue because your first item `sys.path` still remains at `caboose2\` directory when the bot's `__init__.py` is run.

`__init__.py` is used for doing initialization logic for the module, you do not need to import `settings.py` into your `__init__.py` file.

Leave the `__init__.py` file empty and do the following in your `caboose.py` -

```
import bot.settings
settings = bot.settings.get_config()
```

If you really need to import `settings.py` in your `__init__.py` file, try -

```
from bot import settings
```

Comment: Thank you, changing the import statement in `caboose.py` to `import bot.settings` worked. Thank you for your time and helping me understand :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED** 
First read this - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In
>   the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can
>   also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__`
>   variable, described later.

There are 2 options -

**Eeither** use the module export

If you wish to use the `__init__.py` then do this -

- First add and `__all__` to export the method from package -

> File: `__init__.py`:

```
from settings import get_config
__all__ = ['get_config']
```

> File: `caboose.py`:

```
from bot import get_config
settings = get_config()
```

**OR** Ignore the `__init__.py` completely and remove everything from inside it. Then the code in `caboose.py` will work automatically.

> File: `caboose.py`:

```
import bot.settings
settings = bot.settings.get_config()
```

Comment: What do you mean, since I removed `settings` from directory `bot`? The `settings.py` file is in that directory. Also, I tried removing that line, and I now get a different error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'settings'`